# Automatically sanitize values in Formik without validation error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

Formik recommends using Yup to validate data, so basic form looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const SignupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  firstName: Yup.string()
    .min(2, 'Too Short!')
    .max(50, 'Too Long!')
    .required('Required'),
  lastName: Yup.string()
    .min(2, 'Too Short!')
    .max(50, 'Too Long!')
    .required('Required'),
  email: Yup.string()
    .email('Invalid email')
    .required('Required'),
});

export const ValidationSchemaExample = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Signup</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
      }}
      validationSchema={SignupSchema}
      onSubmit={values => {
        // same shape as initial values
        console.log(values);
      }}
    >
      {({ errors, touched }) => (
        <Form>
          <Field name="firstName" />
          {errors.firstName && touched.firstName ? (
            <div>{errors.firstName}</div>
          ) : null}
          <Field name="lastName" />
          {errors.lastName && touched.lastName ? (
            <div>{errors.lastName}</div>
          ) : null}
          <Field name="email" type="email" />
          {errors.email && touched.email ? <div>{errors.email}</div> : null}
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  </div>
);
```

What I need instead is a way to sanitize data without showing a validation error.

For example, a number field that can be a number from 1 to 10. If user enters 20 - it should automatically change to 10 (without showing validation errors).

Is there a way to customize Yup or Formik so form values are updated automatically?

Comment: You need to intercept `onChange` handler for every input and write  your logic there. After than use formik's prop `setFieldValue(formFieldName,Value)` to manually update form values. This should suffice bare minimum requirements for your problem